# How to show variable value in Ajax callback function?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am very  new to Ajax.In ajax function, I cannot show the variable `$competition_id` content.I am using following codes but it show the ID only.

```
function custom_fixture_template(){


  $competition_id = $_POST[ 'competion' ];
  echo  $competition_id;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'football_fixture' ), // profile and letter are CPTs
        'posts_per_page'=>5,
        'meta_key'   => 'pb_match_date',
        'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'competition',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $competition_id
            ),
        ),

        'meta_query' => array(
             array(
              'key'     => 'pb_match_status',
              'value'   => 'fixture'
            ),
      )

   );
      $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
}
add_action("wp_ajax_my_custom_fixture_template", "custom_fixture_template");
add_action("wp_ajax_norpiv_my_custom_fixture_template", "custom_fixture_template");
```

Ajax Code :

```
jQuery(".fixture-competition").change(
                function(){
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url:"<?php echo admin_url();?>admin-ajax.php",
                        type:"post",
                        data:{"action":"my_custom_fixture_template",competion:jQuery(this).val()},
                        success:function(res){
                               jQuery('.competition-container').remove();
                                jQuery('.new-fixture').html('');
                                jQuery('.new-fixture').append(res);
                        }
                    });

            });
```

HTML Codes:

```
<select name="fixture-competition" class="fixture-competition">   
                    <?php 
                     $args = array(
                      'type'                     => 'football_fixture',
                      'child_of'                 => 0,
                      'parent'                   => '',
                      'orderby'                  => 'name',
                      'order'                    => 'ASC',
                      'hide_empty'               => 1,
                      'hierarchical'             => 1,
                      'exclude'                  => '',
                      'include'                  => '',
                      'number'                   => '',
                      'taxonomy'                 => 'competition',
                      'pad_counts'               => false );
                    $competition_fixture = get_categories($args); ?>

                    <option value="Select All">--Select--</option>
                     <?php
                    foreach ($competition_fixture as $competition) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $competition->term_id; ?>">
                          <?php $url = get_term_link($competition);?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $competition->name; ?></a>
                      </option>

                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

Comment: You have a little typo `wp_ajax_norpiv_my_custom_fixture_template` must be `wp_ajax_nopriv_my_custom_fixture_template`.

Comment: Thanks.But how to show the content of $competition_id instead of ID?

Answer (score 0):

Your php function doesn't return anything. So the jQuery script has nothing to append to .new-fixture.

You can do something like

```
$my_query = new WP_Query($args); // be carefull of typo (a php closing tag)
echo json_encode($my_query);
```

then in the ajax response, you'll be able to parse the json response.

```
success:function(res){
        var json = $.parseJSON(res);
        console.log(json);
        ...
}
```

Hope it gives you some hints...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by myself using following codes:

```
<div class="team-league-name-top">
  <?php
    $competition_name = get_term( $competition_id, 'competition' );
    echo $competition_name->name;
  ?>
</div>
```